# Subclassing Formatter crashes on initializer

Tags: swift, initialization, subclass, formatter

I am trying to subclass the Formatter class to perform validation on text fields. The application is crashing when super.init() is called:

```
class LengthFormatter: Formatter {
private var maxLength: Int

init(_ maxLength: Int) {
    self.maxLength = maxLength
    super.init() // BAD_ACCESS crash
}

required init? (coder: NSCoder) {
    self.maxLength = 0
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

I am calling it as follows:

```
nameTextfield.formatter = LengthFormatter(3)
```

where `nameTextField` is a `NSTextField`.

I would like to be able to set the max length upon initialization. As Formatter does not have such an initializer or field, how should this be done?

Comment: I saw the error now. I need to implement (override) the abstract methods. I now want to handle the textchanged events instead but this is another question, I'll delete this one. Sorry.

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you for the link. That question is for UI controls, which I understand are iOS specific whereas NS are macOS desktop. Is this correct?

Comment: I ended up subclassing NumberFormatter instead (which is not abstract) and that works with non numerical values as well, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the crash is due to exception of abstract function in base `Formatter`, which should be overridden like below (tested with Xcode 11.2 / macOS 10.15)

```
class LengthFormatter: Formatter {
    private var maxLength: Int

    init(_ maxLength: Int) {
        self.maxLength = maxLength
        super.init()
    }

    required init? (coder: NSCoder) {
        self.maxLength = 0
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {  // overriden abstract method
        return obj as? String // < example, returned value might depend on context
    }
}
```